Cannot use GPU, CuPy is not installed
I have a GPU enabled machine.
O.S: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
nvcc version: 12.2
Nvidia Driver Version: 535.183.01
Pytorch version 2.3.1+cu121
spaCy version 3.7.5
Python version 3.8.10
Pipelines : en_core_web_sm (3.7.1)
I am using a virtual environment.
I received the output True for the following command
>>>import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()

However, when I ran
>>>import spacy
>>> spacy.require_gpu()

I got the error:
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/abc/spacy_test_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/thinc/util.py", line 230, in require_gpu
    raise ValueError("Cannot use GPU, CuPy is not installed")
ValueError: Cannot use GPU, CuPy is not installed

I installed Spacy with GPU enabled version with the command pip install -U 'spacy[cuda122]'
While installing with the above command I got an warning like spacy 3.7.5 does not provide the extra 'cuda122'
Can anyone please tell me what is the error in my installation?

Try this?
python -c "import cupy; import cupyx"

